# Label won't appear on tkinter pop-up window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've been making an app in python and I made a pop-up window to add a new reminder, but the "reminder", "date" and "time" labels don't appear on the new window. The "add new reminder" label also shows up at the bottom left of the window instead of the top center.

I've tried packing and grid configure, but they still don't show up.

```
def popup():
    pop = tk.Toplevel()
    pop.wm_title("New Reminder")

    label = ttk.Label(pop, text="Add new reminder.")
    label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    label2 = ttk.Label(pop, text="Reminder")
    label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    label3 = ttk.Label(pop, text="Date")
    label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    label4 = ttk.Label(pop, text="Time")
    label.grid(row=3, column=0)

    rem = ttk.Entry(pop)
    rem.grid(row=1, column=1)
    date = ttk.Entry(pop)
    date.grid(row=2, column=1)
    time = ttk.Entry(pop)
    time.grid(row=3, column=1)

    addbutton = ttk.Button(pop, text="Add", command=pop.destroy)
    addbutton.grid(row=4, column=0)
    canbutton = ttk.Button(pop, text="Cancel", command=pop.destroy)
    canbutton.grid(row=4, column=1)

    pop.mainloop()
```

What instead shows up is the three entries stacked vertically at the top with the "add new reminder" label to the left of the last entry

Comment: you need to grid `label2`, `label3` ...  not `label` for all

Answer (score 0):

Layout problems are much easier to visualize when you separate widget creation from widget layout.

Here's your layout code grouped together:

```
label.grid(row=0, column=1)
label.grid(row=1, column=0)
label.grid(row=2, column=0)
label.grid(row=3, column=0)
rem.grid(row=1, column=1)
date.grid(row=2, column=1)
time.grid(row=3, column=1)
addbutton.grid(row=4, column=0)
canbutton.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

Notice how you are calling `grid` on `label` four times, and never call `grid` on `label2`, `label3`, and `label4`.